# Problem to pass variables in "View.OnClickListener" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, variables, onclicklistener

So here's my problem: I'm trying to pass variables from the onCreate method to a View.OnClickListener.  Here is, for example, an activity that works perfectly (and serves as a model for me):

```
package com.thebigbadboy.bataille_corse;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView card1, card2, card3, card4;
TextView cardsplayer1, cardsplayer2, cardsplayer3, cardsplayer4, compteur;
Button b_player1, b_player2, b_player3, b_player4;

private Random r;

float comparateur=0.0f;
byte melange=0, joueurs_tot=4;
int player_actif=0,  a=0, cardnum1=0, cardnum2=0, cardnum3=0, cardnum4=0, count=0;
List<Byte> deck = new ArrayList();
List<Byte> jeuplayer1 = new ArrayList();
List<Byte> jeuplayer2 = new ArrayList();
List<Byte> jeuplayer3 = new ArrayList();
List<Byte> jeuplayer4 = new ArrayList();
List<Byte> jeuplateau = new ArrayList();

private View.OnClickListener btnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b_player1 :
                if (player_actif==1) {
                    player_actif++;
                    melange = jeuplayer1.get(0);
                    jeuplayer1.remove(0);
                    jeuplateau.add(melange);
                    cardsplayer1.setText(jeuplayer1.size() + " cartes");
                    melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-1);
                    cardnum1 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    card1.setImageResource(cardnum1);
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>1) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-2);
                        cardnum2 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card2.setImageResource(cardnum2);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>2) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-3);
                        cardnum3 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card3.setImageResource(cardnum3);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>3) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-4);
                        cardnum4 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card4.setImageResource(cardnum4);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b_player2 :
                if (player_actif==2) {
                    player_actif++;
                    melange = jeuplayer2.get(0);
                    jeuplayer2.remove(0);
                    jeuplateau.add(melange);
                    cardsplayer2.setText(jeuplayer2.size() + " cartes");
                    melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-1);
                    cardnum1 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    card1.setImageResource(cardnum1);
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>1) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-2);
                        cardnum2 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card2.setImageResource(cardnum2);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>2) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-3);
                        cardnum3 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card3.setImageResource(cardnum3);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>3) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-4);
                        cardnum4 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card4.setImageResource(cardnum4);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b_player3 :
                if (player_actif==3) {
                    player_actif++;
                    melange = jeuplayer3.get(0);
                    jeuplayer3.remove(0);
                    jeuplateau.add(melange);
                    cardsplayer3.setText(jeuplayer3.size() + " cartes");
                    melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-1);
                    cardnum1 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    card1.setImageResource(cardnum1);
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>1) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-2);
                        cardnum2 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card2.setImageResource(cardnum2);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>2) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-3);
                        cardnum3 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card3.setImageResource(cardnum3);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>3) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-4);
                        cardnum4 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card4.setImageResource(cardnum4);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b_player4 :
                if (player_actif==4) {
                    player_actif=1;
                    melange = jeuplayer4.get(0);
                    jeuplayer4.remove(0);
                    jeuplateau.add(melange);
                    cardsplayer4.setText(jeuplayer4.size() + " cartes");
                    melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-1);
                    cardnum1 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    card1.setImageResource(cardnum1);
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>1) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-2);
                        cardnum2 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card2.setImageResource(cardnum2);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>2) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-3);
                        cardnum3 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card3.setImageResource(cardnum3);
                    }
                    if (jeuplateau.size()>3) {
                        melange = jeuplateau.get(jeuplateau.size()-4);
                        cardnum4 = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + melange, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        card4.setImageResource(cardnum4);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (byte i = 0; i < 52; i++) deck.add(i);
    card1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card2);
    card3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card3);
    card4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card4);
    cardsplayer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardsplayer1);
    cardsplayer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardsplayer2);
    cardsplayer3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardsplayer3);
    cardsplayer4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardsplayer4);
    b_player1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_player1);
    b_player2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_player2);
    b_player3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_player3);
    b_player4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_player4);

    b_player1.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
    b_player2.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
    b_player3.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);
    b_player4.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);

    r = new Random();

    player_actif=r.nextInt(3)+1;

    for (byte i=0; i<52; i++) {
        a = r.nextInt(52 - i);
        melange = deck.get(a);
        deck.remove(a);
        if (i < 13) {
            jeuplayer1.add(melange);
        } else if (i < 26) {
            jeuplayer2.add(melange);
        } else if (i < 39) {
            jeuplayer3.add(melange);
        } else jeuplayer4.add(melange);
    }
}
}
```

And that code works really perfectly, I can edit the Array List jeuplayer1 etc correctly in the Onclick method. Now I tried to make this works :

```
package com.retroverse.bataille_corse;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import 
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Menu_play_local extends AppCompatActivity {

Button p1,p2,p3,p4;

StringBuilder s_p1,s_p2,s_p3,s_p4;

byte state_p2 = 1, state_p3 = 0, state_p4 = 0;

private View.OnClickListener btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.p2:
            s_p2 = new StringBuilder()
            state_p2++;
            s_p2.append(getString(R.string.menu_loc_op2));
            if (state_p2 == 3) {state_p2 = 1;}
            if (state_p2 == 1) {s_p2.append(getString(R.string.bot));}
            if (state_p2 == 2) {s_p2.append(getString(R.string.human));}
            p2.setText(s_p2.toString());
            break;
        case R.id.p3:
            s_p3.setLength(0);
            state_p3++;
            s_p3.append(R.string.menu_loc_op3);
            if (state_p3 == 3) {state_p3 = 0;}
            if (state_p3 == 0) {s_p3.append(getString(R.string.nobody));}
            if (state_p3 == 1) {s_p3.append(getString(R.string.bot));}
            if (state_p3 == 2) {s_p3.append(getString(R.string.human));}
            p3.setText(s_p3.toString());
            break;
        case R.id.p4:
            s_p4.setLength(0);
            state_p4++;
            s_p4.append(R.string.menu_loc_op4);
            if (state_p4 == 3) {state_p4 = 0;}
            if (state_p4 == 0) {s_p4.append(getString(R.string.nobody));}
            if (state_p4 == 1) {s_p4.append(getString(R.string.bot));}
            if (state_p4 == 2) {s_p4.append(getString(R.string.human));}
            p4.setText(s_p4.toString());
            break;
    }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.menu_play_local);

    Button p1 = findViewById(R.id.p1);
    Button p2 = findViewById(R.id.p2);
    Button p3 = findViewById(R.id.p3);
    Button p4 = findViewById(R.id.p4);

    p2.setOnClickListener(btn);
    p3.setOnClickListener(btn);
    p4.setOnClickListener(btn);

    StringBuilder s_p1 = new StringBuilder().append(getString(R.string.menu_loc_op1)).append(getString(R.string.human));
    StringBuilder s_p2 = new StringBuilder().append(getString(R.string.menu_loc_op2)).append(getString(R.string.bot));
    StringBuilder s_p3 = new StringBuilder().append(getString(R.string.menu_loc_op3)).append(getString(R.string.nobody));
    StringBuilder s_p4 = new StringBuilder().append(getString(R.string.menu_loc_op4)).append(getString(R.string.nobody));

    p1.setText(s_p1.toString());
    p2.setText(s_p2.toString());
    p3.setText(s_p3.toString());
    p4.setText(s_p4.toString());
}
}
```

And unfortunately, this code doesn't work properly (this is normal if there is no code when you touch the p1 button): when you touch the p2 button, the application stops abruptly and here is the error message :[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2i8P.jpg)
The button p2 is considered like a "null object"... Please read carefully the 2 codes, I know it can be very badly done, feel free to advise / correct me.  I really need your help please!

Comment: Remove `Button` from the beginning of each `findViewById()` line in `Menu_play_local`'s `onCreate()` method; e.g., just `p1 = findViewById(R.id.p1);`. As you have it now, you're declaring different local variables with the same names as the fields at the top of the class, and only those local variables are being assigned; the fields remain null.

Comment: I agree, but how to explain that with the model (first code), the application can use without any problem the ArrayList "deck" and "jeuplayer1", etc (they are filled with numbers from 1 to 52 in the "For" loop of the onCreate method)?  And that there is no error message for that code (not even an error telling us we're working on a null object, such as a TextView)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but the first block just has it right. It's already assigning the fields – i.e., the "class level" variables declared at the top, outside of any method. The second block has two different sets of variables with the same names. It's assigning only the local variables in `onCreate()`, so the fields are still null when they're used in the `OnClickListener`. (Btw, it looks like you want to do the same thing for all of those `StringBuilder`s, too, though that's not causing the immediate issue.)

Comment: Ah thank you very much !!!

Thanks to you I found the error: I was indeed initializing twice my variables with the same name, so I had to remove the "StringBuilder" and "Button" in front of the lines of code ^^.  Thank you very much, and one more question : is it inadvisable to do as I do ?

Comment: Nah, that's perfectly fine. Sometimes fields are the only way to do certain things.